# How to install a .deb file on a jailbroken iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I'm developing an app with Xcode for the iPhone (jailbroken). Now I want to install a .deb file programmatically. How can I do this? I could execute a command to install it, but how? Is it enough if I install my app via Xcode on my jailbroken iPhone? (.ipa) or do I need to create a .deb? If yes, how?

Thank you very much!

Have a nice day.

edit: I made a app. In this app I have a file browser (only for documents directory). In this directory there are .deb files. Now, I want to install these .deb files programmatically if the user taps on one. How do I go about this?

Comment: I would like to know that too :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK dpkg -i *.deb is the command to install a .deb. But you cannot install a .deb in a .deb because the package manager is locked thus you need a script or something.

Comment: do i need to make my app into a .deb or is a .ipa enough? What do you mean with script? In the app "iFile" there's a built in deb installer and ifile is a cydia app...

Comment: another question is there a way to move the deb file to "/private/var/root/Media/Cydia/AutoInstall" ?? (that's root)

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't have a iphone.

Comment: @DevMan have you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to function as a package installer, then yes, I would use

```
dpkg -i filename.deb
```

You could execute this command programmatically with a [system()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/system.3.html) call, or an [exec()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/exec.3.html) call, with `"dpkg -i filename.deb"` as the command.  You might want to fully qualify the path to `dpkg` (e.g. /usr/bin/dpkg ... or whatever it is ... I'm not on my phone now) if you use `system()` especially.

It might be that you find that you need to have **root** privileges to do this.  [See this on how to give your app root privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8796556/119114).

Another option, that doesn't require your app running as **root** or using `exec()` or `system()` calls, is to use the technique [I describe in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6503158/119114), which was about how to reboot an iPhone programmatically.  Just as I used a script to call the `reboot` command, you could write a script to execute `dpkg -i filename.deb`.  You'd just need to come up with a mechanism to pass the filename to your script, which I assume would change dynamically (unless your program used a temporary link that always pointed to the current .deb file to be installed.)

Answer (score 0):

Many options.

1. You can learn the source code  of Cydia.( Official site provide source code)
2. Learn source code from Icy Github. https://github.com/ripdev/Icy
3. The simple way, just use system function to invoke dpkg command.

```
NSString *appsyncDebPath=@"/var/root/appsync.deb";
    NSString *cmdString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/usr/bin/dpkg  -i %@ >/tmp/dpkg.log;",appsyncDebPath];
    const char  *cmdChar=[cmdString UTF8String];
    system(cmdChar);
```

You may show result from /tmp/dpkg.log

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK jailbreaking an iPhone let you install ipa without certificates... so it's enough...

Comment: I think you didn't understand me right. I made a app. In this app i have a file browser (only for documents directory). In this directory there a .deb files. Now I want to install these .deb files programmtically if the user taps on one. How to do this?

Comment: as epitaph said: the syntax is dpkg -i filename.deb